# How can I disable default windows hotkeys in flutter desktop application?

Tags: windows, flutter, focus

I want add new actions for f10 key. But when I press f10 my app loses focus and than I can't track keyboard actions with RawKeyDownEvent.

I want disable all default windows hotkeys while user uses app. Is there any way doing this? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this package to register or unregister hotkeys.

https://pub.dev/packages/hotkey_manager/example

```
// ⌥ + Q
HotKey _hotKey = HotKey(
KeyCode.keyQ,
modifiers: [KeyModifier.alt],
// Set hotkey scope (default is HotKeyScope.system)
scope: HotKeyScope.inapp, // Set as inapp-wide hotkey.
);
await hotKeyManager.register(
_hotKey,
keyDownHandler: (hotKey) {
print('onKeyDown+${hotKey.toJson()}');
},
// Only works on macOS.
keyUpHandler: (hotKey){
print('onKeyUp+${hotKey.toJson()}');
} ,
);

await hotKeyManager.unregister(_hotKey);

await hotKeyManager.unregisterAll();
```